# Why same software is taking more time than it took previously?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, performance, sql-server-2008

I am not sure if this a question to be asked in this site. But I am helpless.

I have developed a win form application for my office which imports data from text file into database table. It is running about 6 months now. But recently users complain me that, the application is taking much more time than it took previously. For example, even one month ago, it took around 10 mins to import around 1 million data into database. But recently, the same version of the application took around 30 min to import such amount of data.

I guess, it is not an software issue (as even if in 30 min time, data is imported successfully). If so, what other issue can cause this kind of problem?

I have developed the software using VS2010 C# (target framework 2.0) and MS SqlServer 2008 database.

Comment: * Sorry for the typo. "TOO" will be "took"

Comment: During the lasting 6 months, have you kept all the imported data? If so, your database has grown quite a bit. Could the bottleneck be your database performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right this is not a software issue. You need to look at

1. Is there a network issue? May be not but you need to rule it out
2. When you start importing huge amount rows into a table which already has lots of rows you could face issues because of existing indexes as they have to be updated every time the rows are added. Assuming you are already using bulk import you need to disable the indexes when you import the data and re enable it after you have imported.
3. Not sure what exactly your import program does but you could try your hand at SSIS this is built with such processes in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a database tuning issue. Take a look at what SQL queries are fired at your database and look closely if there are indexes missing. The right indexes can improve performance tremendously. Also look at index defragmentation.